# How to change 1 CSS line after a new page within my website opens after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change 1 CSS line when you click a link in the website and a new page opens. I want to create a ‘order form’ link on a page, which goes to another page and then the order form should open up by changing the display to block of the div that contains the order form.

Is this possible, perhaps with Javascript? I have too little knowledge of Javascript therefore I am asking it here.

Thank you.

Best,
Silvan

**UPDATE: Full code below**

[image]

[Link to actual website page](https://www.en.silvansoeters.nl/prints) and button is called “Order directly”

**UPDATE:** Additional Javascript Click which doesn’t work probably since I’m already using !important on the Display: block.

```
$('.close-icon-form').click(function() {
$('#order-form').css({
    'display': 'none'
});
$('#order-form').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
```

});

**UPDATE:**
I have tried what @Simp4Code said but that does nothing. See screenshots for what I have done. This seems like a solid solution but so far no succes :(

[image]

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE:** Please see the code from @Simp4Code if you are facing a similar problem. It contains code for adding a cookie after clicking a link that will set some CSS to a class (to your liking) and deleting it on click of a button.

Comment: Rather than changing the CSS, what you should be doing is using JS to update elements with classes that already exist within your CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Josh, thank you, but I don’t know where to start writing this code.

Comment: Hi @NathanielFlick, only the code commented by Simp4Code but that isn’t working yet. I don’t have the knowledge yet to write this.

Comment: In the future, please do not provide images in place of code. You should endeavor to provide an [mcve] on StackOverflow and minimize reliance on external links. Once you fix your site the link becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I fully understand @JonP. At the time of this post I didn’t read myself enough into the ways of Stackoverflow. I’m trying to better this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in JavaScript I'd recommend doing this with cookies.

1. Check if the cookie exists, if it does then the body will get a class of `.orderFormVisible`

```
// Regular Expression to check for existence of cookie
if (document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*orderForm\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {

  // If cookie exists add class to <body>
  document.body.classList.add('orderFormVisible');
};
```

---

2. Add click event listener to the button to set the cookie

```
// Get the button by ID
const orderButton = document.getElementById('orderButton');

// Check if button exists before adding click listener
orderButton && orderButton( 'click', function(e) {

  // When button is clicked add a cookie

  // You can set max-age (in seconds) for the cookie lifespan
  // So that the cookie will clear itself shortly after navigating
  document.cookie = 'orderForm=Visible; max-age=10;';

  // To clear cookie manually remove max-age and add path
  /* document.cookie = 'orderForm=Visible; Path=/;'; */
  
});
```

---

2A. *[optional]* Manually clear the cookie

```
// Get the button by ID
const closeButton = document.getElementById('closeButton');

// Check if button exists before adding click listener
closeButton && closeButton( 'click', function(e) {

  // When button is clicked delete cookie
  document.cookie = 'orderForm=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';
});
```

---

3. Use CSS to display the form, something like this

```
.orderFormVisible #orderForm { display: block; opacity: 1 }
```

---

I would recommend you do a bit of reading up about this, [here's a useful MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) where they go into details about security and a cookie max age and so on

Comment: Hi @Simp4Code, I have tried your code exactly like you said but so far I have no succes :( The link of where the order button (“buy prints here”) is located is www.en.silvansoeters.nl/prints

Comment: @SilvanSoeters if you copied it directly it would not work. You need to change the first line in the first code getElementById('myButton') the myButton part should be the id of your button, if your button doesn’t have an id then add one first. I’ll take a look at your website soon and update the answer accordingly

Comment: @SilvanSoeters so the cookie is getting added when you click the button but then it throws an error when the page is redirected because the new page doesn't have a button. You will see I updated the first snippet a little where it checks it exists first `myButton && myButton.addEventListener` see the *myButton &&* part was added. Also, move the second snippet above the first one in your code so that it checks for the cookie before it does anything else

Comment: @SilvanSoeters oh and one last thing, the CSS snippet was updated to have `display: block` and `opacity: 1` because on your site you've set opacity 0 as well as display none

Comment: Hi @Simp4Code, thank you so much! It worked! And it mostly understand it too thanks to your comments about it. There is 1 small problem left. I had to put !important after the CSS style display: block, otherwise the order form just wouldn’t come up. But now when I try to close the order form it doesn’t change the property display: block to none anymore. So I tried to add an additional Click on the close button, even though it already had one, with another !important but this time after ‘none’ so it will close. But it doesn’t work. I added the code I’m using in my main post.

Comment: Hi @Simp4Code, I might have a solution in theory  but don’t know how to do this. Is it perhaps possible to delete the .orderFormVisible class once the page and the order form is loaded? So the !important / styling will be removed? Then I should be able the close it again.

Comment: @SilvanSoeters just remove the `orderFormVisible` class from the body when clicking the close button -- basically the same as code as adding the cookie but then `document.body.classList.remove('orderFormVisible');` which you can put in your jQuery click function

Comment: another problem is when you go to a different page in the website en return to the Gallery, the order form is still open (and you can’t close it now as I stated earlier), this shouldn’t be the case. How do I delete the cookie again once the page is loaded? –

Comment: thank you that worked too! Now I only need to clear the cookie when you visit another page, or when the order form has opened? Because now it will open each time when you visit the Gallery page.

Comment: @SilvanSoeters you could set an expiration on the cookie something like `document.cookie = 'orderForm=Visible; max-age=10';` which would make the cookie expire after 10 seconds. So enough time for the page to navigate but then clears itself automatically. Otherwise you could remove the cookie when you click a button, like the close button on the order form as well as the place order button on the order form

Comment: That was super useful! It’s working perfectly. Many thanks once again.

Comment: @SilvanSoeters glad it's all working! I updated the answer to include what we've discussed. Good luck